# Can I reduce razor code to just few lines?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Can I reduce this razor code?

```
    <li>
    @{
        if (@Model.PublicationDate.HasValue) {
            @Model.PublicationDate.Value.ToString("D", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR")) 
        }
        else {
            @:"pas disponible"
        }
    }
    </li>
```

I was trying this but it doesn't work:

```
@{(@Model.PublicationDate.HasValue) ? (@Model.PublicationDate.Value.ToString("D")) : (@:"pas disponible")}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could decorate your view model property with the [`[DisplayFormat]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:D}", NullDisplayText = "pas disponible")]
public DateTime? PublicationDate { get; set; }
```

and then your view simply becomes:

```
<li>
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.PublicationDate)
</li>
```

So now it is reduced to a single and elegant line.

Comment: You lose the culture info. Which should probably be placed somewhere elese anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can use the [`?:` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(v=vs.80).aspx) to shorten it. If that's a good idea is a different question.

And you probably don't want to hard-code the locale with `new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR")` but use the locale from either a variable or the current locale of the thread.

Comment: I'm thinking to use the current server culture